# Xamarin Forms HttpClient PostAsync does not return response

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms, async-await, httpclient

I'm trying to get API response by passing service url and json parameter. Url and Parameter passing properly to the **requestAPI** function, but doesn't give response from **PostAsync** method. Url is the API location, parameter is the Category Id. When I'm running same API in the browser, it gives correct response. But not in app.

This is **requestAPI** function.

```
public async Task<ResponseObject> requestAPI(string urlString, string jsonParameters)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000); // NOTE: just to simulate a HTTP request over the wire

            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonParameters);
                HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                HttpResponseMessage response = null;

                if (true)       // no issue here.
                {                                                    
                    response = await client.PostAsync(urlString, httpContent);
                }
                else
                {
                    response = await client.PutAsync(urlString, httpContent);
                }

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(@"              TodoItem successfully saved.");
                    var returnVal = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return new ResponseObject{
                        jsonString = returnVal,
                        isSuccess = true,
                        error = null
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ResponseObject
                    {
                        jsonString = null,
                        isSuccess = false,
                        error = null
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
                return new ResponseObject
                {
                    jsonString = null,

                    isSuccess = false,
                    error = null
                };
            }
        }
```

Category Id comes from this method.

```
private async void loadBookList(string categoryId)
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                ResponseObject responseObject = await _apiService.requestAPI("http://192.168.0.35/kiyawamu-api/index.php/rest/V1/mobileappintegration/getbookdetailsbycategory", Convert.ToString(categoryId));

                if (responseObject.isSuccess)
                {
                    var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BookListJsonObject>(responseObject.jsonString);
                    CategoryBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>(jsonObject.booksByCategory);
                }
                else
                {
                    giveAlertForCommonError();
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried following solutions, but doesn't work.

1. Url used as a uri `var uri = new Uri(urlString);`
2. jsonParameter also used as a string
3. *GetAsync* also used

Any assistance on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Android or iOS? Is this code in a PCL?

Comment: `but doesn't give response from PostAsync method` what do you mean by this, what status code are you getting. how are you calling this

Comment: This code in PCL @Daniel. I'm running only Android project.

Comment: When run the debugger, it gives response -> `response = {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent` @TheGeneral

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It does return a response. Not Found is a response. Check the body of the response to see if there is a message about the request.

Comment: You coorect @Nkosi. Not Found is also response. But that means there are no any value in response. In my working responses, it gives -> `response = {StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent`

Answer (score 1):

If you're running it on Android and the code is in a PCL, try to add ModernHttpClient so you can use the native HttpClientHandler.

https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient

But I also recommend all to upgrade from PCL to .NET standard. If you do so you don't have to install a NuGet package to use HttpCliennt. And then you can select implementation of HttpClientHandler in project settings.

Comment: Appreciate your answer Daniel. But Will it gives a solution ? Then why doesn't PostAsync return a value ?

Comment: ModernHttpClient has solved similar problems for me many times.